# Attempt to install Google Eclipse plugin gives error

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to install Googles' eclipse plugin - http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html

Even on following all the right steps I get an error message - Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.3 requires plug-in "org.eclipse.jdt.core".

But I could not find how to install this missing plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [Eclipse 3.3 update site](http://update.eclipse.org/updates/3.3/) first. Then proceed with the Google Eclipse plugin installation and it will find the required components.

Comment: Using the update site above installed missing pieces. But Googles' plugin also requires WST which can be installed from http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/

Answer (score 0):

the JDT component you can download here

[JDT Core Component](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php)

[SDK For Eclipse 3.3](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3.2-200802211800/index.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But am still not there.
On the page http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php > Under the section 'R3.3 Maintenance' > download link takes me here - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ > what to do next?

I already have Eclipse installed with loads of plugins and settings customized. I do not want to install fresh intance of eclipse.

Comment: there are different versions of eclipse. Some eclipse contain more plugins, than the other one. It is like jre and jdk. You have to install eclipse which contains the JDT plugins, or copy them into your eclipse plugins directory or use the update site mechanism from eclipse